# create .html or .txt file instead of .jpx file in spring roo

Tags: java, spring-roo

I want to create .html or .txt file instead of .jpx file in spring roo but i am unable to do this.

```
web mvc setup
web mvc all --package com.visualinsights.web
```

This commands in spring roo create the .jpx file internally and I don't know how.
If I want to create my own html file with .html extension in the time when I put commands in roo shell and I don't want .jpx file then what I have to do?

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `web mvc all` or `web mvc scaffold` commands roo will generate .jspx files on web layer... is not possible to specify format of generated files...

If you want to report as improvement on Spring Roo project, you can do it on:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO

Best Regards,

Comment: Spring Jira server is down... try later.